I want the join operation to occur after 10 minutes using Pyflink table api?
i have loaded two tables using pyflink table api from 2 different kafka topics and i want to join these two tables based on common columns. In this, i wanted my join operation to wait some time after my execution. how to do join operation to wait?
I tried temporal join but it was not working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
